Ubiquiti EdgeRouter-X port forwarding limited to LAN only
I am wanting to swap from my existing back-end reverse proxy (NGinx, which is currently working) to a new HAProxy solution. Note: I have "Enable hairpin NAT" set.
I change the port-forwarding IP from 192.168.0.252 to 192.168.0.254. From an internal machine the traffic passes through to the HAProxy fine, but not external traffic. When I switch back to NGinx it works again.
I've dumped the configuration to see if there are any filters for 192.168.0.252, but nothing found.
I appreciate this is probably an edge case, but other viewpoints might help me pin-point potential causes.

Found the cause and capturing for anyone else who finds this.
The server being port-forwarded too was in the DHCP reservation list, and was not using a static IP, which it did not seem to like.
I applied a static IP and removed the reservation, swapped the port-forwarding over and things are working as expected.
